# Maven-generated GWT Servlet not Responding

Tags: gwt, servlets, maven

I used the GWT Maven plug-in (version 2.3.0) to generate a GWT project. The nice thing about that is that the Maven plug-in takes care of generating the async part of the service. Everything appears to work but the servlet is not responding both when running in hosted mode (running in Jetty) and when deploying the resulting WAR to Tomcat.

My problem is now that the servlet is simply not responding. The `onSuccess()` callback is invoked but all I get are `null` values. I pretty much copied the tutorial from the GWT homepage, so my  service is created in the this way:

```
final StatusServiceAsync statusService = GWT.create(StatusService.class);
```

Here is my service interface:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("status")
public interface StatusService extends RemoteService
{
    String getStatus(String someInput);
}
```

As already mentioned, the async counterpart is generated by the Maven plug-in. The web.xml looks like this:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>statusServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>my.package.StatusServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>statusServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/StatusBoard/status</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>StatusBoard.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

At first, I thought the configuration is totally wrong so I played around with it a little bit. When I changed the `<servlet-class>` value, the servlet container logged an `ClassNotFoundException`. Then I changed the `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` I also got an error. So the configuration can't be totally wrong.

Here is the server-side code (I stripped it down to see that nothing else could go wrong):

```
public class StatusServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements StatusService
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3317511632727461036L;

    @Override
    public String getStatus(final String someInput)
    {
        return someInput;
    }
}
```

Sorry that I forgot that detail but sometimes, the debugger doesn't recognize the breakpoint in the servlet. But even when it does, the returned value is still `null`.

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Just in case: does your servlet inherit from RemoteServiceServlet and implements StatusService?

Comment: You could use Firebug (for Firefox) to sniff the request/responses (network tab) and inspect the request and responses. I can compare your request/responses with my projects' to see differences...

Comment: Yes, the servlet does inherits from RemoteServiceServlet and implements the service interface.

Comment: Can you show us the servers side code (the remote servlet)?

Comment: I added the server-side code to the original question.

Comment: I insist: try Firebug to see what request/response is happening (you should see a POST to /StatusBoard/status)

Comment: Is your GWT module named "StatusBoard", or do you perhaps have a "rename-to" name set?

Comment: Thanks, Jason482, this was the decisive hint. I renamed quite a bit of stuff in the original sample project that the GWT plugin created. The module was one of them. Another thing was the generated async class. It uses the `@ RemoteServiceRelativePath` annotation's value as part of the entry point's URL. This wasn't updated properly. You have to run a `mvn gwt:clean` to delete the autogenerated GWT stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @Jason and Robert: one of you should post that as an answer and Robert should then mark it accepted. Robert: putting "[SOLVED]" in the title is not the right way to show that a question has an accepted answer.

Comment: I removed the [SOLVED] from the title. @RobertB, if the Jason482's answer is ok, as it's suggested by your comments, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, your GWT app has a base URL from the module name. If you have used the "rename-to" attribute in your gwt.xml file, then that value will be your base URL. In this case, looking at your web.xml entries, your module should be named "StatusBoard." Or change your URL to your "rename-to" value.